# Tabbed text in label

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create an Android app that contains the World 8 Ball Pool Rules (https://www.epa.org.uk/Downloads/Rules_World_Rules_2019.pdf), to make it easier for me to have a mobile version of the rules, and develop my skills with xamarin.forms

Some of the rules have sub rules

e.g.
When playing from the Baulk:

1. The centre point of the Cue Ball.........
2. The Cue Ball can be moved......
3. The Cue Ball may be played.....

I'm trying to add the list, or at least indent the text in a label to format the string to look like the above.

Is there a special sequence of characters to create the tab (like 
 is for new line)?

Comment: `\t` is the tab character

Comment: It doesn't work in Xaml. It just displays the '\t'

Comment: in XAML try `&#x09;`

Comment: Check [Wrapping paragraphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter03) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I would probably use separate `Label`s and use a margin to indent them. It is far neater than the horrible syntax you would need to do it in a single `Label`. Examples:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="When playing from the Baulk:"
           BackgroundColor="Red" />
    <Label Text="1. The centre point of the Cue Ball........."
           BackgroundColor="Red"
           Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <Label Text="2. The Cue Ball can be moved......"
           BackgroundColor="Red"
           Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <Label Text="3. The Cue Ball may be played....."
           BackgroundColor="Red"
           Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <Label Text="When playing from the Baulk:&#x0a;&#x09;1. The centre point of the Cue Ball.........&#x0a;&#x09;2. The Cue Ball can be moved......&#x0a;&#x09;3. The Cue Ball may be played....."
           BackgroundColor="Blue" />
</StackLayout>
```

gives:

[image]